# Resizing a CStatic control dynamically to fit text

Tags: c++, mfc, resize, controls

As of now, I'm using the following to code to resize my `CStatic` controls:

```cs
WINDOWPLACEMENT wndpl;
m_myStaticControl.GetWindowPlacement(&wndpl);

// Increase the static box's width
wndpl.rcNormalPosition.right += 10;

m_myStaticControl.SetWindowPlacement(&wndpl);
m_myStaticControl.SetWindowText("Some text");
```

I obtain the constant (in the above case, 10) by trial-and-error. Because this seems like a really inelegant and hard-to-maintain solution, I want to change this. After some research, I think I have a basic idea; which is:

1. Get the pixel width and height of the required text using [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28VS.85%29.aspx).
2. Get the current window placement of the `CStatic` control as in code example above.
3. If the current width < obtained pixel width, add obtained pixel width. Do the same for height.
4. Set the window placement as in code example above.
5. Set the window text as in code example above.

Would this be a good, efficient approach? Also, does `GetTextExtentPoint32` use pixels or dialog units?

Comment: The GetTextExtentPoint32 approach is correct for me.

Comment: `pixels or dialog units`? Neither.  GetTextExtentPoint32 returns logical units, based on the mapping mode of the device context argument.  Which might be pixels for your case.

Comment: @MarkTaylor, Are [these the mapping modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145045(v=vs.85).aspx) you were talking about?